# Rename the newest file's extension

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a command script (`.cmd` file) that will find the newest file and rename its extension.

So if there is:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

And `file3.txt` is the newest, the script should change the extension to `.xml`, so the end result will be `file3.xml`.

If I do the following it will rename the file's extension:

```
move file3.txt file3.xml
```

But I don't know how to find the newest file, and then change its extension.

Comment: Please define *newest*. Latest modification timestamp? Largest number in the file name?

Answer (score 0):

You could use following batch code:

```
@echo off
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /O-D /TW "C:\Temp\Test\*.txt" 2^>nul') do (
    ren "C:\Temp\Test\%%F" "%%~nF.xml"
    goto :EOF
)
```

The command **DIR** returns a list of file names matching pattern `*.txt` without path and without any other data because of `/B` (bare format) sorted reverse according to last modification date (newest first) because of `/O-D /TW`.

This list is processed line by line by command **FOR** which executes for first file name the rename command to change the file extension for newest `*.txt` file in the specified directory. The loop and the batch file processing is exited after renaming first file because of `goto :EOF`. `EOF` is a predefined label which means End Of File.

If the current directory on running the batch file is always the directory with the text files, the batch file could be coded also as:

```
@echo off
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /O-D /TW *.txt 2^>nul') do (
    ren "%%F" "%%~nF.xml"
    goto :EOF
)
```

`delims=` turns off splitting the file name returned by command **DIR** into tokes by spaces in case of the newest file contains 1 or more spaces in file name.

`2^>nul` redirects any error message because of no `*.txt` file in current respectively specified directory to device `nul` to suppress this error message whereby the [redirection operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) `>` is escaped here with `^` because of using it within command **FOR**.

`%%~nF` means file name only without file extension and dot separating the file extension from file name.

For understanding the used commands even better and how they work here, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `ren /?`